# Google charts not accepting well formed array

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Im writing a charting tool using the Google charts API.
To change the timespan for the data that makes up the charts i'm sending a jquery post to a jsp servlet that returns a string line that looks similar to

```
Swedish#68#Pasta#4#Vegetarian#2#Seafood#2#Salad#1
```

it is stored in the string data that is then split into a two dimension array which is what I use to create the charts rows.

```
                data.trim();
                var dataArray = data.split("#");  
                var catChartArray = new Array((dataArray.length/2));
                for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length/2;i++)
                    {catChartArray[i]=new Array(1);}    
                var j =0;
                for (var i = 0; i<dataArray.length/2; i++){
                    catChartArray[i][0]= dataArray[j];
                    catChartArray[i][1]= dataArray[parseInt(j+1)];
                    j+=2;
                }
```

Then I pass it to an instance of google.visualization.DataTable() with the addRows(catChartArray) method. At this point the chart will not draw and I cant understand why. It has used exactly that kind of when constructed and then it works fine.
Im quite unexperienced using Javascript so I might have overlooked something very obvious.
A printout of the array shows nothing spectacular:

```
Swedish,68,Pasta,4,Vegetarian,2,Seafood,2,Salad,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your processed data looks like this:

```
[["Swedish", "68"], ["Pasta", "4"], ["Vegetarian", "2"],...
```

Shouldn't it be like this:

```
["Swedish", "Pasta", "Vegetarian"...
["68", "4", "2"...
```

Comment: I dont think so. Its a two dimensional array. If I just print   `drawCategoriesChart([['Swedish', 11], ['Pasta', 40], ['Vegetarian', 12], ['Seafood', 22], ['Salad', 1]]);` in the loading script it runs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
Two things created the bugs in the system.

This of course produces no errors:

```
catChartArray[i][1]= dataArray[parseInt(j+1)];
```

but it should be

```
catChartArray[i][1]= parseInt(dataArray[j+1]);
```

Also the servlet returned alot of empty lines that must have disrupted the array.
Added

```
 <%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
```

to my the jsp file i used for the post request.

Now everything works as expected.