# Google Charts not accepting correctly formatted array as row data

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization

Before I ask, I would just like to point at that I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174331/google-charts-not-accepting-well-formed-array) answer, and it didn't work for me. This is not a duplicate question.

I am inserting an array into Google Charts as row data, however I am receiving the error `Uncaught Error: Every row given must be either null or an array.` in the console.

When logging my array in the console, it looks like this: `[1, 1.96, 1.96, 1.96]` This is exactly the same format as normal arrays shown in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart), yet it is still being rejected.

Why is this? I've tried many things and I can't get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var chartData = [];
    var json = $.getJSON('myjsonlink', function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            chartData[i] = [];
            chartData[i][0] = parseInt(data[i].sales);
            chartData[i][1] = parseFloat(data[i].profit);
            chartData[i][2] = parseFloat(data[i].profit);
            chartData[i][3] = parseFloat(data[i].profit);
        }
        console.log(chartData[0]); // This prints out [1, 1.96, 1.96, 1.96]
    });

    data.addColumn('number', 'Hour');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Pageviews');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Earnings in $AUD');

    data.addRows([
        chartData[0]
    ]);

    var options = {
        width: 450,
        height: 250
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('todays-total-sales'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You're messing something up with your    `data.addRows([chartData[0]]);`. As said in the [full API    documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addRows) `addRows(numOrArray)` should be given either a    number or an array to populate your rows, but you're giving it an    array within an array, therefore it doesn't work.
       Removing the brackets `[]` around `chartData[0]`</strike>

Frankly I thought I understood what I was talking about, but after starting typing I clearly don't. I made a fiddle where it is working, either populating the rows with a `for-loop` and populating everything row by row, or by passing the complete variable `chartData` instead of `chartData[0]`. Check it out [at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/reL5hd30/3/).

Someone who have a better understanding would be very appreciated to add a reply with a better explanation.

Comment: Somehow that magically solved the problem. By using `data.addRows(chartData);` instead of `data.addRows([chartData[0]]);`

Despite them technically achieving the same result, one worked and the other didn't.

Comment: I belive that it might be from the `addRows` expected multiple rows, and passing `chartData[0]` only validates as a single row.

Comment: maybe, but it's weird because I put `chartData[0]` inside an array.

Comment: but you still only applided 1 array in that array. maybe `[chartData[0], chartData[1]]` would work? But as I said, this is 100% guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this problem today, and notice this page is top in Google for the error.

My solution was that some of the values were null in the database, which were being translated to empty strings.

I was generating the JS code using server-side logic.  Coalescing nulls to zeros fix my problem.

Fairly obvious on reflection, but until I had pasted my code into CodePen it wasn't obvious to me...