# "Row given with size different than 3" Google Charts

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization, klipfolio

I'm using Google Charts inside of a system called Klipfolio. Been tinkering with it for days. Curious if anyone else has tried the same. This issues isn't particular to Kipfolio but I figured a little bit of background may go a long way.

This is the code:

```
var _component = this;
var _dataModel = this.dataModel;
var thearray = $.map(_dataModel, function(value, index) {
 return [value];
});
var thearrays = ('['+thearray.toString()+']');
var datadone = (JSON.parse(thearrays));
console.table(datadone);
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'From');
data.addColumn('string', 'To');
data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');

data.addRows([datadone]);

    // Sets chart options.
    var options = {
    sankey: {
        iterations: 700,
        node: {
            label: {
                fontName: 'Arial',
                fontSize: 12,
                color: 'rgb(74,74,74)',
                bold: true,
                italic: false
            },
            interactivity: true, // Allows you to select nodes.
            labelPadding: 3, // Horizontal distance between the label and the node.
            nodePadding: 20, // Vertical distance between nodes.
            width: 10, // Thickness of the node.
            colors: [
                'rgb(82,144,233)', // Custom color palette for sankey nodes.
            'rgb(113,179,124)', // Nodes will cycle through this palette
            'rgb(206,226,55)', // giving each node its own color.
            'rgb(239,209,64)',
                'rgb(236,147,47)',
                'rgb(225,77,87)',
                'rgb(150,89,148)',
                'rgb(157,121,82)',
                'rgb(154,146,137)']
        }
    }


};

    // Instantiates and draws our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_basic'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

The **_dataModel** variable outputs in console.table as this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDudd.jpg.

The **thearray** variable outputs in console.table as this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/73o76.jpg

When the chart renders, it throws up the error:

> Uncaught Error: Row given with size different than 3 (the number of columns in the table)

Are there any other steps I should take to eliminate this error? I'm new to using javascript and objects/arrays. I see that the **thearray** variable has 4 columns that appear, but is that the issue?

Comment: Your screenshots doesn't really show the formation of your JSON that you try to add to your chart. Please arrange something better to review, preferebly so we can see it in string-format. Absolutely best in a fiddle.

[You can read the google API JSON-format here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like my issue was adding the brackets on data.addRows function. So instead of:

```
data.addRows([datadone]);
```

which didn't generate, I replaced it with:

```
data.addRows(datadone);
```

Thanks Henrik for pointing me to look at the data source. Once I verified the formation, I was able to identify the issue and fix it. Chart looks great now!

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

For some more reference about this, and how to format `data.addRows(X) // data.addRows([X]) // data.addRow(x)` etc we discussed about it just last week.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264149/google-charts-not-accepting-correctly-formatted-array-as-row-data/31266253?noredirect=1#comment50571790_31266253