# Row given with size different than 2” Google Charts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to visualize a column chart using `Google Chart` and `jQuery(1.10.2)` but it throws following error.

> [console log] : "Row given with size different than 2”

Before marking this as answered, i tried as suggested ["Row given with size different than 3" Google Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404309/row-given-with-size-different-than-3-google-charts), but no chart is rendered.

```
function drawChart() {
    var jD = $.ajax(
        {
            url: "http://localhost/tapme/data.php",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;
    var options = {
        title: 'Google API example',

        vAxis: {
            title: 'Score on a scale of 1 to 10'
        }
    };
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(`JD`);
    data.addColumn('string', 'uid');
    data.addColumn('number', 'm1high');
    var dataArray = [];
    $.each(JSON.parse(jD), function (i, obj) {
        dataArray.push([obj.uid], parseInt(obj.m1high));
    });
    data.addRows(dataArray);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('cdiv'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I am unable to figure out the error. Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each data row should be wrapped in a single array,
which should include all columns

here, only the first column is wrapped in an array,
and the second column is left out...

```
dataArray.push([obj.uid], parseInt(obj.m1high));
```

try changing to...

```
dataArray.push([obj.uid, parseInt(obj.m1high)]);
```